# Styling data that is fetched from api in angular

Tags: angular

I have fetched data from api and I am getting output (all usernames stored in api) as -

```
 Leanne Graham
 Ervin Howell
 Clementine Bauch
 Patricia Lebsack
 Chelsey Dietrich
 Mrs. Dennis Schulist
 Kurtis Weissnat
 Nicholas Runolfsdottir V
 Glenna Reichert
 Clementina DuBuque
```

Now suppose if i want to do some styling like padding:20px, then entire list of names will move 20px. How to style a particular name in this list?? 
 Suppose i want to style (like margin or padding) on the particular name only, then is it possible to do that??

Here is my code -

home.component.html

```
 <div *ngIf="dataItem?.length>0">           
      <div *ngFor='let x of dataItem'>
             <div class="design">
                {{x.name}}
             </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

home.component.css

```
 .design
   {
     padding-left: 20px;
   }
```

home.component.ts

```
  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
     dataItem:any = {} 
     constructor(private data: DataService) {
        this.data.getuserdetails().subscribe(item=>{
          console.log(item);
          this.dataItem=item;
       });
      }
     ngOnInit()
         {}
     }
```

home.service.ts

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
   getuserdetails(){
     return this.http.get<any> 
    ('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .pipe(map(item => {
        return item;
    }));
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you take firstName and lastName separately instead fullName *[if you are working with Real Time project then]*

Comment: Its not about first name or last name.  i just  want to style a particular name like " Leanne Graham" or " Ervin Howell", then is it possible to do that ???

Comment: yes, you can do that with ngClass

Comment: Suppose i want "Leanne Graham" only with the margin-left as 20px , then can u please tell me how to apply ngclass in that case. I have mentioned my code in the question

Comment: Check the posted answer! Have provided sample demo

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could achieve what you want, I suggest using CSS selectors.

For example, for applying only to the first name, your could declare your CSS class as:

```
.design:first-child
{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

And it will automatically apply only tot he first name ( since the first name is the only first child of your list. )

For more selectors and their function, [you can take a look here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

A few side notes:

As it is written, you don't need the`map` operator in your service, you can simply write:

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
   getuserdetails(){
     return this.http.get<any>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
}
```

It is better to subscribe in `ngOnInit` to be sure everything is properly setted in the view:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
     dataItem:any = {} 
     constructor(private data: DataService) {}
     ngOnInit(){
         this.data.getuserdetails().subscribe(item=>{
          console.log(item);
          this.dataItem=item;
       });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

```
<div class="design" [ngClass]="{'customClass': x.name =='Leanne Graham'}">
   {{x.name}}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.customClass {
  margin-left: 20px
}
```

[`WORKING_DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymzxav)